# Returning newly-added record in EFcore

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I am doing a prototype using EFCore and struggling with a good way to return the object I've just added to a collection on an entity.

For example:

```
public Songleader AddSongleader(int congregationId, Songleader songleader)
{
    var congregation = _dbContext.Congregations.Include(c => c.Songleaders).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == congregationId);
    congregation.Songleaders.Add(songleader);                        
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();

    //TODO: return the recently-added record...
    return null;
}
```

A `Congregation` has a collection of `Songleaders`. Once I save the context, though, I'm not sure of a good way to return the new instance. The `Id` of the Songleader is generated when it's inserted to the DB so I can't just return the object I passed into the method...

Is there a good strategy for this or something baked into EF to help in this scenario?

Comment: Did you wanted to exclude the Id property from the model ?

Comment: Songleader contains (int)Id, (string) FirstName, (string) LastName. But the Id is actually assigned by DBMS, not by the caller. So, prior to SaveChanges(), it's certainly 0. This is a repository method that's underneath an API controller where the input method is a DTO that only contains the FirstName/LastName and Automapper converts it to Model.

Comment: Unless they drastically changed the way EF behaves in EF7, which they may have as I haven't worked with it yet as it's still missing key features, the ID generated by the database should be set on the object you added after you added it. This was the default behaviour in EF6. As I said though, they may have done away with that behaviour in EF7.

Comment: Yep, you're exactly right. `songleader` that comes in as a parameter gets added to the collection, then its ID is set, and if I return `songleader`, it's got everything I expect set. Just a basic 'pass by reference' thing I overlooked. Bleh! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return the `Songleaders` back to the caller or just the integer value which return by `SaveChanges()` method. Its all depend on your requirements you.

From controller you can use `CreatedAtRoute` method to return the response.

Here is a good tutorial which you can read. It mention some HTTP recommendation for Rest API.

[Building Your First Web API with ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api)

Comment: Wow, maybe I'll just blame this on late development. `songleader` gets updated after `.SaveChanges()` because it's passed by reference and so just returning `songleader` returns exactly what I want. Wow. Thanks for the sanity-check, though :)